# IExpress. How to setup folder as datasource in iexpress SED format?

Tags: iexpress

I'd like to know about two things about SED format in iexpress.exe

Q1: How to setup folder as datasource in SED format?

Q2: Where is exist an official documentation about this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t add an entire folder via IExpress; you can only add individual files. And each file to be added must be specified.

I don’t believe there are any extant, public, official docs from Microsoft on the SED file options. The best I’ve seen so far is this website:

http://www.mdgx.com/INF_web/cdfinfo.htm

But as you can see, it’s not very detailed either.